# Java8: convert one map to another map using stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I need to convert a Java `HashMap` to an instance of `TreeMap` (including map contents)

```
HashMap<String, Object> src = ...;
TreeMap<String, Object> dest = src.entrySet().stream()
        .filter( ... )
        .collect(Collectors.toMap( ???, ???, ???, TreeMap::new));
```

What should I put in place of `???` to make this code compilable?

Comment: Why not just `new TreeMap<>(src)`?

Comment: Because I need to filter the stream and drop some values

Answer (score 44, accepted):

From [Collectors.toMap(...) javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-):

```
 * @param keyMapper a mapping function to produce keys
 * @param valueMapper a mapping function to produce values
 * @param mergeFunction a merge function, used to resolve collisions between
 *                      values associated with the same key, as supplied
 *                      to {@link Map#merge(Object, Object, BiFunction)}
 * @param mapSupplier a function which returns a new, empty {@code Map} into
 *                    which the results will be inserted
```

For example:

```
HashMap<String, Object> src = ...;
TreeMap<String, Object> dest = src.entrySet().stream()
      .filter( ... )
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey , Map.Entry::getValue, (a,b) -> a, TreeMap::new));
```

Comment: Does this also work with a parallelStream or do we have to use ConcurrentSkipList then?

Comment: @KIC "Implementation Note:
The returned Collector is not concurrent. For parallel stream pipelines, the combiner function operates by merging the keys from one map into another, which can be an expensive operation. If it is not required that results are inserted into the Map in encounter order, using toConcurrentMap(Function, Function) may offer better parallel performance." https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to convert map into stream:

> Use of Stream.of(t)

```
HashMap<String, Object> src = ...;
TreeMap<String, Object> dest = Stream.of(src)
      .filter( ... )
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey , Map.Entry::getValue, (a,b) -> a, TreeMap::new));
```