# Java order TreeMap by value descending using Collections.reverseOrder()

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, treemap

I'd like to sort an existing TreeMap (or copy the values from a Map into a TreeMap, doesn't matter) in an descending order, sorted by value (Doubles).

I know there are a lot of similar questions posted here, but afaik in Java8 you can accomplish this without creating an own Comparator, but using Collections.reverseOrder.

Somewhere there was an answer which described exactly this. Based on it, I tried to implement it:

```
private Map<String, Double> orderByDescValue(Map<String, Double> unorderedMap) {
    Stream<Map.Entry<String,Double>> sorted = unorderedMap.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()));
    return sorted.limit(Configuration.WORDCLOUD_SIZE)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

}
```

I understand this doesn't work because it returns a Map, which doesn't assert any order, instead of a TreeMap. But Collectors doesn't seem to have a toTreeMap, I can't cast it - and I do not know what else to do.

Or maybe it can't work this way and I have to solve this another way?

Comment: TLDR: You technically can't. However, there is another way. I'll post it in my answer

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31004899/java-8-collectors-tomap-sortedmap

Comment: BTW you can use `Entry.comparingByValue().reversed()`

Comment: Use the version of `Collectors.toMap` that takes a supplier.  Provide as your supplier a method that returns a new `TreeMap` with the appropriate comparator passed to the ctor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the fact that a `LinkedHashMap` will retain insertion order - so specify a supplier in the `toMap` call so that it will create a `LinkedHashMap` appropriately:

```
.collect(Collectors.toMap(
    Map.Entry::getKey,
    Map.Entry::getValue,
    (x, y) -> { throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected merge request"); },
    LinkedHashMap::new));
```

That won't be a `TreeMap`, but your method doesn't declare that it returns a `TreeMap`, just a `Map`. If you really, really need a `TreeMap`, I suggest you change the signature - but that would be odd, given that a `TreeMap` sorts by key rather than value.

Complete example:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Double> unordered = new HashMap<>();
        unordered.put("a", 10.5);
        unordered.put("b", 5.3);
        unordered.put("c", 12.7);
        unordered.put("d", 6.0);

        Map<String, Double> ordered = orderByDescValue(unordered);
        for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : ordered.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    private static Map<String, Double> orderByDescValue(Map<String, Double> unorderedMap) {
        return unorderedMap.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                Map.Entry::getValue,
                (x, y) -> { throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected merge request"); },
                LinkedHashMap::new));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
c: 12.7
a: 10.5
d: 6.0
b: 5.3
```

Additionally, you don't need to limit your method to only handle that type of map - you can make it generic:

```
private static <K, V extends Comparable<V>> Map<K, V> orderByDescValue(Map<K, V> unorderedMap) {
    return unorderedMap.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Map.Entry::getKey,
            Map.Entry::getValue,
            (x, y) -> { throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected merge request"); },
            LinkedHashMap::new));
}
```

(I'm sure I could add a bunch of `? extends K` or whatever, but I've left it in a simpler form for now...)